# AllDifferent Constraint in Pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to run a MINLP problem on Pyomo. I have formulated an objective function and one of my constraints is this:

```
model.c2 = Constraint(expr = sum(model.x[i] for i in blocks) <= 4560)
```

I want something like this:

x+y+z<=3 with x not equal to y not equal to z.

How do I write a constraint for this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends a bit on the details (are the variables integers, are all values in the domain covered). Here is a reference that may be of interest:

> Williams, H. Paul and Yan, Hong (2001), Representations of the
>   'all_different' predicate of constraint satisfaction in integer
>   programming, Informs Journal on Computing, 13 (2). 96-103.

Let's define the problem more precisely. Say we have `n` integers, `x[i]`, that take unique values between `1,...,n`. We can implement this as:

We can introduce binary variables

```
 y[i,k] = 1 if x[i]=k
          0 otherwise
```

With this, we can write:

```
 x[i] = sum(k, k*y[i,k])   (1)
 sum(k, y[i,k]) = 1   ∀i   (2)
 sum(i, y[i,k]) = 1   ∀k   (3)
 y[i,k] ∈ {0,1}
```

where `i ∈ {1,..,n}` and `k ∈ {1,..,n}`.

If you have fewer variables than `n`, say `i ∈ {1,..,m}` with `m < n`, then we need to replace (3) by:

```
 sum(i, y[i,k]) ≤ 1   ∀k   (3a)
```

Comment: All the variables are integers lying between 1 to 96 and all the values should be different.

Comment: Any alternative non-subscript based method to code for x not equal to y in Pyomo? Unable to implement the above formulation for my model.

Comment: I can not fathom any reason why this approach is not trivial to implement in Pyomo.